# Flutter | How to remove specific key from Shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-layout

here I want to delete the particular product from my cart. and my cart is generated using shared preferences data. so basically I want to remove the particular index from shared preferences.
Hope you understand the question. also here i am using on listview builder for display the data.

Here is code of shared preferences,

```
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
List<String> cartitems = preferences.getStringList('cartItems');

 return ListView.builder(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: unauthCartItems.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    print(unauthCartItems.length);

    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        //Here i want to clear the Preferences based on index
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: you saved the shared preference right? so you must already know the key for each value, then use that key to update the value.

Comment: yes, i've already i just want to remove those key values from Shared preferences. but how I dont know. can you please help

Comment: show the value of your list and the item you want to remove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the item from the list and save it back to the preference.

```
     cartitems.removeAt(index);
​
     preferences.setStringList(cartitems)
```

Comment: [dart] The method 'saveStringList' isn't defined for the class 'SharedPreferences'.

i am getting this issue

Comment: it was a type, use setStringList.